# Is there an easy way to send unicode string to windows clipboard in perl?

Tags: perl

Is there an easy way to send unicode string to windows clipboard in perl? I have tried Win32::Clipboard, but it seems doesn't work, ü will become nonsense.

```
use Win32::Clipboard;

$CLIP = Win32::Clipboard();
$CLIP->Set('Büchner');

$CLIP->WaitForChange();
print "Clipboard has changed!\n";
```

Comment: Win32::Clipboard doesn't currently permit this, so you'd have to reimplement it using Win32::API. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jandubois/win32-clipboard/pull/5) that would add the ability to set arbitrary text

Answer (score 0):

With `Win32::Clipboard` you can only write `CF_TEXT`, i.e. encoded in the current code page, to the clipboard. `CF_UNICODETEXT` is not supported. But you can encode the string you want to write to the clipboard using the current code page.

The code page can be obtained using [`Win32::GetACP()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32). It needs `cp` to be prepended, so that `encode()` can use it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Encode qw(encode);
use Win32;
use Win32::Clipboard;

my $to_clip = 'Tschüß!';

my $cp = Win32::GetACP();

my $clip = Win32::Clipboard();

$clip->Set(encode("cp$cp", $to_clip));
```

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for the pointer about `Win32::GetACP()`! That's indeed way easier. I amended the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your method works for accented character, but it seems that it is not working for arbitrary unicode symbol. for example, try this `1−x`